# How to add the VC editBarItem to the navigationItem from storyboard?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, tableview

This seems like such a simple question, but I can't get it working for the life of me.

If I manually add a `UIBarButtonItem` to the `UINavigationItem` via Storyboard, and set its 'System Item' attribute to 'Edit', it does *not* seem to trigger `setEditing:animated:` when pressed.

However, if I add the right bar button item manually in code, like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
}
```

then the button does correctly trigger that method.  Importantly, it also automatically changes to 'Done' for the duration of editing (which a manual call to `setEditing:animated:` from an `IBAction` won't do).

Is there a way to set up that automatic connection from storyboard?

Comment: i think the storyboard just gives the button of that type,but not its implementation. You can have edit button as left/right button on storyboard but it doesnt mean, when you tap on it,it should do that action!!!!